# How to select rows based on a column's with fix number of top values in data frame?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame such like:

```
df0 <- data.frame(x=c(-5, -4.5, -3, -2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                  y=letters[1:12])
df0
     x y
# 1  -5.0 a
# 2  -4.5 b
# 3  -3.0 c
# 4  -2.0 d
# 5   0.0 e
# 6   1.0 f
# 7   2.0 g
# 8   3.0 h
# 9   4.0 i
# 10  5.0 j
# 11  6.0 k
# 12  7.0 l
```

What I wanted it to subset 6 rows of the `df` from both sides based on column `x` (namely 3 from bottom minimums and 3 from top maximums of `x`) such like:

```
df1<-data.frame(x=c(-5, -4.5, -3, 5, 6, 7),
                y=c("a", "b", "c", "j", "k", "l"))
df1
#    x y
# 1  -5.0 a
# 2  -4.5 b
# 3  -3.0 c
# 4  5.0 j
# 5  6.0 k
# 6  7.0 l
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df[c(1:3, (nrow(df)-2):nrow(df)), ]
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `head` and `tail`

```
rbind(head(df0,3), tail(df0,3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **dplyr** way:

```
library(dplyr)
df0 %>% filter(!between(row_number(), 4, n()-3))
```

This is, however, more verbose and slower than the other answers here. The only reason to use this answer would be to bolster the Hadley hegemony.

```
library(microbenchmark)

mplourde <- function() df0 %>% filter(!between(row_number(), 4, n()-3))
akrun <- function() rbind(head(df0,3), tail(df0,3))
ven <- function() df0[c(1:3, (nrow(df0)-2):nrow(df0)), ]
microbenchmark(mplourde(), akrun(), ven())

# Unit: microseconds
#        expr    min     lq   mean median    uq     max neval
#  mplourde() 474.69 505.19 551.39 520.30 551.2 2165.59   100
#     akrun() 253.74 275.69 301.21 291.37 310.8  746.10   100
#       ven()  38.77  48.04  53.72  51.75  58.3   91.23   100
```

Comment: `slice(df0, c(1:3, (n()-2):n()))` is another dplyr option